# Why are Yubico Yubikeys limited to 32 OATH accounts?

Tags: password-management, account-security, multi-factor, hardware, yubikey

Is the 32 OATH QR code account limit on Yubikeys due to a storage constraint?

Because the Yubikey 5 series has been out for a few years now it'd be amazing if there is a new version released soon with increased OATH account capacity.

Comment: I'd suggest asking Yubico. Questions that begin "why" are often down to design choices, so not usually answerable here

Comment: Great idea @RoryAlsop. I've submitted a support ticket too and will update the post with new info learned. This could potentially be a good question for those experienced in hardware design that do not work for Yubico, and understand the technical constraints of multi-factor authentication (MFA).

Comment: There's great potential technical explanations in [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/yubikey/comments/178ju53/will_yubico_increase_the_32_limit_of_oath/).